# Proper use of React JS & JavaScript libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, backbone.js, reactjs

I'm working in a small agency and we build multilingual websites that are complex enough to have me thinking about using a JS library, but not big enough to be considered a "Web App". We have developed our own "stack" that includes WordPress as the CMS and multiple tools (PHP module loader, JavaScript module loader, css preprocessors, build tool, etc.)

Most of our sites have various modules and forms that are used in multiple pages.  For example in our current project one of this module makes several calls to an API and there are multiple event bindings to do in each pages.

I was considering using BackboneJS but feel like it's a bit overhead for this kind of project. Then I looked in React but since the modules doesn't always require to repaint the DOM, I wasn't sure it would be used properly. I care a lot about producing optimal and maintainable code (don't want to put everything in one big js file) so I'd like to find a solution. Unfortunately most documentations and examples I found for these libraries were for one-page apps or projects with only one module so it didn't help.

Anybody have suggestions as to what to use? Someone in a similar situation committed to a library and could give some feedback?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think you need a framework? If you already have a JavaScript module loader, just organize your modules. You can use React if you want to write your templates in a higher level language than HTML, want something other than php, while also helping your organize your views.

Comment: +1 @azium , a lot of people abuse frameworks loading them for simple js functions which has a cost for the user. if the alternative to not using a framework is a lot of code (some frameworks require just as much code as vanilla js to find elements, etc) then it might make sense. But one thing you can do as a company is create common functions, use objects to keep it neat, should make things a lot quicker

Comment: I'm not convinced I need a framework, was just curious to see if it could help without being too much of an overhead. If you think I using a  module-loader with some kind of router (to load module "foo" in page "bar") is good enough, it actually reassure me!

Comment: React is going to be confusing if you're doing half standard DOM/html stuff and half React (or some split like this). unless you want to do a big overhaul and start replacing html and vanilla JS with React, piece by piece (component by component :) then I wouldn't touch React.

Comment: Great advice, thanks @LukeSchunk